# Pivot without aggregation

Tags: sql, pivot, amazon-redshift

How can I pivot the output so each id will refelct a primary and secondary min_score.  current output is long and I need wide. Having to use rate to create a classification and the subsequent group by statement is tripping me up.

```
 select id,
         min(score) as min_score,
         case
                when rate >  0 then 'Primary'
                when rate = 0 then 'Secondary' 
                when rate is null then 'Secondary'
                        else 'Unknown'
                                end as Primary_Secondary
 
 from abc
 group by id, rate
 order by id
```

Current Output

| id | min_score | Primary_Secondary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 24 | Primary |
| 12 | 0 | Secondary |

Required Output

| id | min_primary_score | min_secondary_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 24 | 0 |

Comment: Please include the starting sample data that would generate your desired output; [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  id,
  MIN(CASE WHEN                 rate > 0 THEN score END) AS min_primary_score,
  MIN(CASE WHEN rate IS NULL OR rate = 0 THEN score END) AS min_secondary_score,
  MIN(CASE WHEN                 rate < 0 THEN score END) AS min_unknown_score
FROM
  abc
GROUP BY
  id
ORDER BY
  id
```

Comment: @MatBallie TY, I knew there was a simple soultion I was not thinking of, lol was creating temp tables and pivot